# Does Post-back of Credit card # requires PCI compliance?

Tags: credit-card, pci-compliance

I have a html form that contains credit card related fields. If those fields are posted back  will I need to be PCI compliant? even though I will not be reading or storing them at server.

Comment: Yes, you transferring sensitive data so it must be appropriately secured.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are capturing sensitive data, you are responsible to guarantee its secure processing or you can use a certified payment gateway to avoid this, but it depends of your project's requirements.

You can take look to [PCI DSS Overview](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf) document, specifically at page 5 where you'll find the next quote:

> PCI DSS provides a baseline of technical and operational requirements 
>   designed to protect cardholder data. PCI DSS applies to all entities involved in payment card processing – including merchants, processors, 
>   acquirers, issuers, and service providers, as well as all other entities that store, process or transmit cardholder data.